# How to show the relationship in neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

> I've attached the sample input comma separated value file and a hand drawn image showing my expected output down below.

```
Problem Description:
--------------------
```

I have a CSV file containing a list of nodes where each line denotes a relationship of node at line[0] with every other list of nodes line[2],line[2],line[3].....line[4500] in that line

Ex. Sample Input File:

```
0,1,2,3 (line 1)  
1,2 (line 2)    
2,4 (line 3)  
3,7,19 (line 4)  
10,4,5,11 (line 5)
```

Please note (line 1),(line 2) etc. is not present in actual CSV file. Here I've named them just for sake of explanation.

```
for line 1 (Let 'line') node at 
line[0] i.e. "0" has a directed "friends" relationship with 
nodes at line[2] i.e "1" 
nodes at line[4], i,e."2"
nodes at line[6], i,e."3"

similarly again for line 2 (Let 'line') node at 
line[0] i.e. "1" has a directed "friends" relationship with 
nodes at line[2] i.e "2" 

similarly again for line 3(Let 'line')  node at 
line[0] i.e. "2" has a directed "friends" relationship with 
nodes at line[2] i.e "4" 


similarly again for line 4(Let 'line')  node at 
line[0] i.e. "3" has a directed "friends" relationship with 
nodes at line[2] i.e "7" 
nodes at line[4], i,e."19"

and so on....
```

what i am trying to do is I want to show a graph in Neo4j depicting the suggested friend relationship among each nodes.

what I cannot figure out is how to iterate the whole **csv** file as well as capture the relationship among each nodes on each line of **csv** file.

Please Note:[I have attached the expected hand drawn output of a sample input file.]

> [Link to Comma separated value file containing the friends](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saurabhkumar1903/neo4j/master/alterFile/sampletestoutput1.csv)
>
> [Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmVWV.jpg)

Comment: You're trying to write this in Java? How far have you got - is it the CSV processing or the Node4J side of things that you're having trouble with? The [Apache CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library is pretty good if you need a way to handle the CSV.

Comment: No I want to show the relationship in Neo4j graph database.

Comment: OK, but how are you trying to import that data into Neo4J so that you can visualise it? When you say "what I cannot figure out is how to iterate the whole csv file" have you tried to write some code to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, save your CSV file into Neo4j import directory (take a look in [Neo4j files location docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations)). After, use Neo4j [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) statement to import your data. The script I used to reproduce your desired output is as follow:

```
// Load the csv file
load csv from "file:///friends.csv" as line
// calculate the indexes from the second column to the last
with line, range(1, size(line) - 1) as indexes
// merge (create or assign) the node from first column (0,1,2,3,10)
merge(a:Node{id:line[0]})
// pass 'a', 'indexes' and 'line' to the next context
with a, indexes, line
// unwind the indexes into single index per row
unwind indexes as index
// merge (create or assign) the node from other columns
merge(b:Node{id:line[index]})
// merge the relationship between a and b
merge(a)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(b)
```

The output considering your sample CSV file will be:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks Bruno Peres it helped!